# Lots of broken links?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, broken-link

Today, I was using Stack Overflow as before and 5 out of 10 links I clicked were broken. A question was marked duplicate to a broken link.

Why are there a lot of broken links now? Or was it a coincidence?

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988/how-to-learn-python
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317983/best-book-to-learn-python
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617794/python-book-for-beginniner

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988/how-to-learn-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317983/best-book-to-learn-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617794/python-book-for-beginniner

Comment: All of which are off-topic questions anyway, and this is one of the reasons why.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Some questions which is linked from well up-voted answers also point to 404. Thought this might be some server error and need some attention.

Comment: **This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation**. Seems to explain it all to me.

Answer (score 11):

Data.SE [Find duplicates of deleted posts.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/177487/find-duplicates-of-deleted-posts) can be a useful query to run.  And yes, there are a lot of them.  This query shows nearly 2100 existing questions that are duplicated to deleted posts.

This is something that 10k users should be poking at from time to time and either going through and acting to close and delete the posts that are duplicates (as the question they are duped to is closed (off topic, unclear, too broad, not constructive, too localized, etc...) and deleteable (something people didn't want on the site).

The two options are:

- Delete the post too
- Flag it for a mod to clear the duplicate (and close it for some other reason?)
- Flag the deleted post to be undeleted and historically locked.

The flag the deleted post is something that only 10k+ users can do (the rest of us see a 'removed because of' page).

---

With some URL twiddling, one can see all the questions that lead to a deleted question (even if you can't see the deleted question)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/XYZ?lq=1

This shows all the linked questions for a post numbered XYZ.

Thus:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/17988?lq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/317983?lq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/5617794?lq=1

should be looked at to see if the post needs to be handled in one of those ways.

Comment: +1. Is there any chance of a third option: the duplicate is on topic, the original one was not, and therefore, the duplicate should be unduplicated?

Comment: Some questions which is linked from well up-voted answers also point to 404. Thought this might be some server error and need some attention.

Comment: @AndreSilva yep - I've got it in before the edit.  It is a possibility.  Though something that 10ks and mods can look at is how popular that deleted post was.  Does it have huge up votes and views?  Consider undeleting it and historically locking it. I think there's a feature request for some process / flag / warning for "this question is the target of duplicate closes" when deleting, though I can't recall off hand.

Comment: @IndrajithIndraprastham the 404 is "this page is no longer accessible" - its not gone (if its on StackOverflow).  It is something that people with [moderator access](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) need to do to help keep the place clean.

Comment: @MichaelT I used 404 just because page title says 
"Page Not Found"

Comment: @IndrajithIndraprastham that is indeed the error code, and the proper error code to return in this case. It helps search engines deindex pages that are no longer accessible to the general public. if you have 10k rep, you would instead see the deleted post and can make additional informed decisions based on that for what should be done.

Comment: In this case, I would imagine that a user did just that (deleted his/ her duplicate) hence the broken link.